# Setting the attribute values to and from the (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 28 elements. Within each two, call them "top" and "bottom". I need to set the "top" and "bottom" elements of the attribute with a value from 0 to 6, and so that all elements were 28 different combinations of "top" and "bottom" elements. Like domino pieces (from 0-0 to 6-6). How to do it jQuery?

```
$(function () {
    var domino = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle'
    });
    var dominoTop = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'top'
    });
    var dominoBottom = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'bottom'
    });

    $('.wrapper').append(domino);
    $('.draggable').append(dominoTop, dominoBottom);

    var i = 0;
    while (i < 27) {
        $(domino).clone().prependTo(".wrapper");
        $('.top').attr('number', i);
        i++;
    };

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        stop: function () {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please put up your code done till now

Comment: did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: can you please explain litle bit more with some examples

Comment: put your code (done until now) on jsfiddle

Comment: You've probably never seen dominoes. If you read the terms and look at the example, I think you will understand.
http://jsfiddle.net/8z68T/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something with for loops rather than while loops and cloning.. you would then need to apply your draggable functionality after they've been generated however.

```
$(function(){
    var topOptions = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    var bottomOptions = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

    var generateDominoes = function(){
        var html = '';
        for(var x = 0; x < topOptions.length; x++){
            for(var y = 0; y < bottomOptions.length; y++){
                html += '<div class="domino draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">';
                    html +='<div class="top">'+x+'</div>';
                    html +='<div class="bottom">'+y+'</div>';
                html += '</div>';
            }
        }
        return html;
    };
    $('.wrapper').html(generateDominoes);

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        stop: function () {
            // insert stop function here
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Generation DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8z68T/1/)**

PS. not really understanding the '28' reference you're making. Permutations of 0-0 to 6-6 = 7^2 = 49

Comment: updated with your added code